# load javascript after loading the page

Tags: javascript, load, deferred

I have read a lot of topics and tried a lot of stuff but I can't get what I want.
I just moved my js code at the end of the page and now I get some errors.

This is how my page looks like:

```
<html>
   <head>
      bla bla
   </head>
<body>
   bla bla
   <div class="advertising">
      <script type="text/javascript" defer="defer">
          window.onload = adsense();
      </script>
      <script type="text/javascript" src="http://pagead2.googlesyndication.com/pagead/show_ads.js">
      </script>
   </div>

  <script language="javascript" type="text/javascript" src="fonctions.js"></script>
</body>
</html>
```

In fonctions.js I have my google adsense code:

```
 function adsense(){
    <!--
    google_ad_client = "pub-xxxxx";
    /* 120x600, date de création 11/06/11 */
    google_ad_slot = "xxxxx";
    google_ad_width = 120;
    google_ad_height = 600;
    //-->
    }
```

The idea was to have the same code for adsense at only one place but I can't get it to load after the file fonctions.js

I tried defer="defer", window.onload ...

Any ideas?
Thanks

I get this error in Firebug:
Error : adsense is not defined

PS: I would like to avoid to use Jquery (to avoid making pages too big)

UPDATE:

```
<script type="text/javascript" defer="defer">
        (function() {  // 'sandbox' javascript pattern to prevent clobbering
                       // global namespace
            var executeProxy = function() {
                if (typeof adsense === 'function') {  // adsense is configured
                    adsense();
                } else {  // adsense is not configured;
                          // therefore, try again later
                    setTimeout(executeProxy, 50);
                }
            };
            executeProxy();
        }());
    </script>
    <script language="javascript" type="text/javascript" src="fonctions.js"></script>
```

in fonctions.js if I put the following code, the "ok" is displayed:

```
function adsense(){
alert ("ok");
}
```

However if I have this code, the ad is not displayed:

```
function adsense(){
google_ad_client = "pub-xx";
/* 120x600, date de création 16/04/11 */
google_ad_slot = "xxx";
google_ad_width = 120;
google_ad_height = 600;
}
```

My guess is that it's a Google issue... The code cannot be loaded in this way...?
If I put the adsense code in the page (below the call - where you do *alert('here');* ) it is well displayed... So my adsense code is correct

UPDATE:
I have finally changed the solution, I've put the code in a .html file and I include it using php. So it's not in my js file anymore.
Thanks for your help anyway.

Comment: _What error do you get_?

Comment: Error : adsense is not defined

Comment: do this -- `window.load = function() { adsense(); };`

Comment: @greengit It's better, now the error disappeared but the add is not displayed on the page

Comment: remove `<!--` from the adsense() function, and `//-->` also

Answer (score 3, accepted):

`window.onload` expects a function callback; however, you are executing `adsense` with `adsense()`, and `adsense` doesn't return a function; therefore, `window.onload` will discard that. Change to:

```
    window.onload = adsense;
```

UPDATE

The above answer should be discarded, but I'm leaving it up so that people can know that `window.onload` expects a function callback :)

Keep in mind that `defer` on the script element will instruct the browser to wait until the page has been loaded to execute the script; however, your `fonctions.js` is in the `src` attribute of your last `script` tag; therefore, your deferred script will most likely execute before  `adsense` has been defined,  because the browser will make an http request to retrieve your script. This will allow deferred scripts to continue executing while `adsense` is not defined. Try this in place of your original deferred script:

```
    <script type="text/javascript" defer="defer">
        (function() {  // 'sandbox' javascript pattern to prevent clobbering
                       // global namespace
            var executeProxy = function() {
                if (typeof adsense === 'function') {  // adsense is configured
                    adsense();
                } else {  // adsense is not configured;
                          // therefore, try again later
                    setTimeout(executeProxy, 50);
                }
            };
            executeProxy();
        }());
    </script>
```

UPDATE

I forgot that script defer is not supported in anything outside of IE. Therefore, the deferring issue should not be at play here; however, I tested the following code in FF and Chrome, and it works:

```
    <script type="text/javascript" defer="defer">
        (function() {  // 'sandbox' javascript pattern to prevent clobbering
                       // global namespace
            var executeProxy = function() {
                if (typeof adsense === 'function') {  // adsense is configured
                    adsense();
                } else {  // adsense is not configured;
                          // therefore, try again later
                    setTimeout(executeProxy, 50);
                }
            };
            executeProxy();
        }());
    </script>
    <script type="text/javascript">
        function adsense() {
            alert('here');
        }
    </script>
```

Comment: Thanks for you help but that still doesn't work.
If I put a alert("ok"); just after adsense(); it's displayed but the ad is still not displayed.

However if I insert my fonctions.js before that script, the ad is displayed...

Comment: can you show the actual code in question as you have it in your environment? When I say the actual code, I mean the code the html portions that you have updated that are actually there while you're having problems.

Answer (score 1):

`window.onload = adsense();` calls `adsense()` *immediately* and assigns its return value to `onload`.